# Override the MSBuild task

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

In order to test my MSBuild 3.5 scripts, I would like to mock some of the build in tasks. My approach has been to inject a UsingTask in my build script to provide an alternative implementation, a la:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="BuildStep" AssemblyFile="MyMocks.dll" />
```

This has worked very well for Message and BuildStep, but when I try to do the same for the MSBuild task my mock is silently ignored and the build in version is used.

Does anyone know how to override the MSBuild task with an alternative implementation?

Thanks,